# commerce 2.x server error when trying to add store

Tags: commerce

Via Composer I have added and enabled commerce 2.x to an existing site. I first added a currency. But when I try and add a store I get a 500 server error. So I then added items I was able to access like order type, order, product variation, etc. But I am still not able to add a store. However, I was finally able to get to the add store screen via the promotion page. Once I added a store I again got a 500 server error. The best I can determine from the server log files is a missing piece.
"....No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Drupal Answers is not a place for bug reports, and this exact problem is already getting attention in the module's issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2859472